# Magento 2.2.6 - Custom modue setup version for module is not specified

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

I try with this but my local system is working fine but the same module when I upgrade in live site then is not working it gives the exception please let me know what I have to do?

Please see below error which I face,

[image]

Comment: check Ref: https://webnoo.com/support/knowledge/magento-2-setup-version-module-not-specified-fix/

Comment: @Rakesh thanks for reference every this is fine with the module just i have to

chmod 775 /magento/app/code/vendorname/modulename -R to do this step on live server and its working fine and error was gone. 

Thanks for your reference link.

Comment: you can download your old module then you can disable your module after app/etc/config.php file remove your module here then your module delete in app/code directory after run below command 
`rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*` then run regular command for extension installation

Comment: @rakesh yes i have solved using your reference link given.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change module file/folder permission

Wrong file/folder permission may cause this error, you should try to set proper permission first, run this command in Magento 2 CLI

```
chmod 775 /magento/app/code/vendorname/modulename -R
```

**Remove module from app/etc/config.php** 
If you see the error after removing a module of Magento, then try to remove the module in config.php file located in app/etc/config.php, for example:

```
return array (
 'modules' =>
  array (
    'Magento_Core' => 1,
    'Magento_Store' => 1,
    'Magento_Theme' => 1,
    'Magento_Authorization' => 1,
    'Magento_custommodule' => 1,
...
  ),
);
```

Remove the unwanted module (for example:  `Magento_custommodule`   ) and save the file. Finally clear cache to see if the error is gone.

[Reference](https://webnoo.com/support/knowledge/magento-2-setup-version-module-not-specified-fix/)